# New Closing Reason needed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we get the closing reason for [event-based-effects](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-based-effects)?  Some of these questions need to be locked/closed based on such event expiration.  So for example Closing Reason: **Event Expired**

Comment: we only get 3 custom close reasons, so would have to remove one of the other ones first :/

Comment: Why do these questions need to be closed after expiration?

Comment: @Bernhard Because any possible answers after the event will be irrelevant and we had I think a couple of questions like that received answers which were not helpful and some spam.

Comment: That is in my opinion not a reason to close the question, but to moderate/review the answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/removing-editing-closing-obsoleting-out-of-date-questions

Comment: @pnuts The Olympic games are every two years, so this remains relevant. If you're looking for a better example, see my last question.

Comment: @pnuts But revolution in Ukraine doesn't seem to be a recurring event.

Comment: @pnuts It should.  I was just reiterating the necessity of possibly closing questions with event based effects but I guess downvoters don't agree.

Answer (score 6):

SE sites only get three custom close reasons, and currently they are as follows for Travel-SE:

- price-shopping for specific goods or services
- immigration
- constructing travel and tour itineraries

Also, I don't think there's a specific reason to close those questions -- they all carry a time stamp, so users should be aware information may not be valid any longer, due to the nature of the event. SE community obviously carries no (legal) responsibility as to whether the information is accurate, so I don't think there's much more to be done.

However, I'd argue that a post notice would be nice in such occasions, but unfortunately the available ones are not modifiable by Travel-SE mods.

Comment: agree, though I still wish we had a better name for this tag

Comment: @KateGregory: You and me both ;) [Suggestions welcome](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/event-based-effects) though.